# NTPD fails to update time correctly

Tags: arch-linux, ntp, ntpd

After getting my Arch laptop to connect to my phone's hotspot, I was having trouble connecting to *any* websites that were't cached (for the most part, anything but Google).

I looked a little, and found that even though it was deprecated, `ntpdate` worked to update my time correctly:

```
sudo ntpdate -u time.nist.gov
```

That gave me the correct time. But I was still having issues connecting, this time supposedly with DNS, or so Chromium was telling me. Still couldn't connect to anything other than Google, but at least the date issue had been fixed... or not.

I looked back at my clock and the time was back where it was before, two hours ahead. I checked `systemctl` and `ntpd` was still running, and it evidently thought it was the correct time.

Why does `ntpd` think the time is correct, and why would I still be having DNS issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, in my case, that because my phone was maintaining a connection to a proxy in a timezone two hours ahead, when my laptop (that 'didn't know' it was connected to a proxy server) was trying to connect to websites, it was sending the wrong time for my timezone.

Upon disconnecting from PIA (the proxy service) on my phone, everything went back to normal.

Comment: This seems very strange. If I connect to an office of ours the other side of the world and use that as my egress point, I don't have any issues accessing websites (apart from latency, that is). Was your proxy aggressively rewriting every HTTP header?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. I didn't want to follow it all the way back from Chromium -> Linux -> Mobile Hotspot -> Proxy. It's entirely possible though. I used the Private Internet Access Android app if anyone is interested in checking/can replicate the issue.